# Snowflake, using REGEXP_REPLACE to match a pattern and replace it by a single dot

Tags: regex, replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to replace any amount of whitespace (If any), followed by `"."`, followed by any amount of whitespace (if any), by "." only.

I can match this string `"     .      "` , for example in notepad easily with this regex :

```
\s*\.\s*
```

and replace it by a single `"."`

However in snowflake this is doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('      .      ', '\s*\.\s*', '.')
```

Returns `...` instead of one `.`

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('just_a_test_string', '\s*\.\s*', '.')
```

This, which shouldn't match at all, returns  : `...............`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So the first correction is to escape the dot like you do in notpad++

aka

```
\s\.\s
```

the next correction, is to understand the regex is double parsed. Once by the SQL parse, and a second time by the regexp parser, so needs escaping:

```
SELECT column1
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '\s*.\s*', '.') as r1
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '\\s*\\.\\s*', '.') as r2
from values 
('.'),
('. '),
(' .'),
(' . '),
('just_a_test_string');
```

thus r2 works as it's is correctly double escaped.

| COLUMN1 | R1 | R2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| . | . | . |
| . | .. | . |
| . | .. | . |
| . | ... | . |
| just_a_test_string | ............... | just_a_test_string |

Comment: Thank you very much the double parsing is exactly what had me troubled

Answer (score 0):

The dot . in regex represents any character, it is like a universal symbol for everything, that is why it is returning so many dots, because it is matching everything.

This type of regex symbols can be escaped by using \ before that, so in your case regex would be '\s*\.\s*'.

Comment: Hi, shoudn't this return, nothing? It's still returns only dots.
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('just_a_test_string', '\s*\.\s*', '\.')

Comment: Try double escaping , \\. , or delimiting the regex string with $ and not single quotes, $\s*\.\s*$